# Is pointer = &buffer[0] redundant?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was recently reading through some source code and read the following at the beginning of a function:

```
char buffer[ 1000 ];
char *pointer;
pointer = &buffer[0];
```

I guess I don't understand this. Why not just write:

```
pointer = buffer;
```

Is there some secret meaning I am missing here?

Comment: "some secret meaning" --> `&buffer[0];` does insure `buffer` is not an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Both expressions give the same result value. So in your given case it is mainly a question of preferred style.

But there is a difference if you use the expresions for example in a function call. A static code analysis tool should complain about

> memcpy(&buffer[0], src, 2 * sizeof(buffer[0]));

because you state that you are writing two elements into one array element. But the tool should not complain about

> memcpy(&buffer, src, 2 * sizeof(buffer[0]));

or

> memcpy(buffer, src, 2 * sizeof(buffer[0]));

because you now say that you want to write into the complete array.

Relevant parts in the [standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf):

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> **3** Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type “array of type” is converted to an expression with type “pointer to type” that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]
>
> **6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**
>
> **Semantics 3** The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type “type”, the result has type “pointer to type”. [...] Similarly, if the operand is the result of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor the unary* that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator were removed and the [] operator were changed to a+ operator. Otherwise, the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its operand.

Comment: It should certainly complain about `&buffer` as you almost never want to do that -- its a bug waiting to happen when someone refactors the code and turns `buffer` into a function argument...

Comment: @ChrisDodd Not that I would write `&buffer`, but can you please explain what could go wrong in the case you mention?

Comment: If `buffer` is  a function argument, then the compiler silently turns it into a pointer instead of an array.  Then `&buffer` gives you the address of the pointer, not the address of the array (in the pointer).

Comment: @ChrisDodd So you are thinking about the case when the user refactors buffer to not be an array anymore but a pointer like `pointer` in the question. Then, of course, understood.

Answer (score 2):

Some people may find it easier to understand depending on the occasion.

Someone might say that when you use `pointer = buffer;` you intend to use the pointer as the buffer,

while if you use `pointer = &buffer[0];` you intend to use the pointer as a pointer or an item of the buffer.

It just happens that those 2 cases point to the same address.

Comment: For "pointer to buffer" usage would certainly be `pointer = &buffer;`, no?

Comment: @png: No you would never want to do that because, a) it's a type mismatch, and b) if someone later changes buffer to be a pointer (such as by making it a function argument), the behavior changes completely and likely leads to obscure bugs.

Answer (score 1):

They're absolutely the same. I also prefer the simpler version

```
pointer = array; // implicit conversion from array to address of its 1st element
pointer = &array[0]; // explicitly set pointer to the address of array's 1st element
```

In some cases, depending on how you're going to use the pointer, the explicit version may be more self-documented.

Answer (score 1):

From C Standards#6.5.2.1

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))..

So,

```
&buffer[0]
```

can be written as

```
&(*(buffer + 0))
```

Note that the operator `&` is used to get the address and the operator `*` is used for dereferencing. These operators cancel the effect of each other when used one after another. So, it is equivalent to

```
(buffer + 0)
```

which is nothing but

```
buffer
```

So, `&buffer[0]` is equivalent to `buffer`.

Comment: Nice compact explanation H.S.